# Javascript get data from Web Service

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, web-services

I am new to web app development I am trying to make a log in page and get the data of user from a local database using javascript. But I am having trouble finding where I did something wrong. Here is my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#log-in-form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var username = $(this).find("input[type=text]").val();
    var password = $(this).find("input[type=password]").val();

    Authentication(username, password);

});

function Authentication(username,password){
    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "../Web Service/LogIn.asmx/get_uinfos",
        data: "{'domain':" + username + "', 'accountpassword':'" + password + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var result = response.d;
            var length = response.length;

            $.each(result, function (index, data) {
                var alias = data.alias;
                window.localStorage.replace("Main.aspx");
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Function Error "get_uinfos"')
        }
    });
}



});
```

and I am connecting to the local server using web service using these code

```
using Wishlist_2017;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;


namespace Wishlist_2017.Web_Service
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for LogIn
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class LogIn : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        dbconn dbcon = new dbconn();

        public class uinfos
        {
            public int id;
            public string alias;
            public string monito;
        }

        static List<uinfos> _get_uinfos = new List<uinfos> { };
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        [WebMethod]
        public List<uinfos> get_uinfos(string domain, string accountpassword)
        {
            DataTable table = null;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "Retrieve_UserInfo";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Domain", domain);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", accountpassword);

            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            table = this.dbcon.ExecuteDataTable(cmd);

            _get_uinfos.Clear();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                uinfos _list = new uinfos();

                _list.id = Convert.ToInt32(row["id"]);
                _list.alias = row["Alias"].ToString();
                _list.monito = row["Monito"].ToString();

                _get_uinfos.Add(_list);
            }

            return _get_uinfos;
        }
    }
}
```

but upon trying to log in by filling the username and password I encounter this error on the console

[image]

can someone help where to look it will be much appreciated

EDIT 1:

This is the code for the class of server

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Wishlist_2017
{
    public class dbconn
    {
        string objConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Server"].ToString();

        public dbconn()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }

        public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(objConn))
            {
                try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = cn;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                        cn.Close();
                }

                return dt;
            }
        }

        public void ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(objConn))
            {
                try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = cn;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                        cn.Close();
                }
            }
        }


        public object ExecuteScalar(SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            object result = null;

            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(objConn))
            {
                try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = cn;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;
                    result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                        cn.Close();
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
    }
```

the connection string is defined on my web.config

EDIT 2:

This is the connection string on my web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Server" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\ArnServer; initial Catalog=Wishlist; uid=sa; pwd=ordiz@2017!; Asynchronous Processing=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Can you include the class definition for your server code? Also, nice to see you're using SQL Parameters considering you are new to web dev :)

Comment: @James please see the edit. Is that what you mean? Thank you, but I can't make it work.

Comment: What is in your `LogIn.asmx.cs`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's where my web service code is located. It's the second block of code.

Comment: Show the full code of it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman okay please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one. It took me some time to realize the issue. The error said it can't create an instance of the `Wishlist_2017.Web_Service.LogIn`. The files you supply seem to indicate it is there where it should be and the file seems okay.

However, in the constructor context, there is this call: `dbconn dbcon = new dbconn();`. If that one fails, it might cause the type creation to fail in a not very specific way.

Analyzing further, it seems that the `dbconn` file has a similar way of initializing the connection:

```
string objConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Server"].ToString();
```

If that one fails, the creation of `dbconn` will fail and the `LogIn` will fail subsequently. It seems the connection string has another name or there is some configuration invalid.

Try to see if removing the `objConn` initialization from `dbconn` solves the type creation problem.

Comment: Agree, namespaces look good, and only thing preventing the class from instantiating would be the no `Server` connection string in `web.config`.

Comment: That's what I thought :) @James

Comment: I tried using the credentials on my web.config but it seems that my credentials is correct. Please see the edit on my post

Comment: Yeah, but the name on it is wrong, or something else, but that call is causing it.

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia change `dbconn dbcon = new dbconn();` to `dbconn dbcon = null`, this will rule out our line of thinking. It will still fail but you'll get a different error (most likely `NullReferenceException`)

Comment: @james you may be right, the error message changed `Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/get_uinfos'.`

Comment: Indeed, so that is another issue. The origin issue is fixed. Run with the debugger attached and set a breakpoint at the `dbconn` initialization. See why it breaks then.

Comment: I think its because of the connection string on my web config. Because the same class works on my friend

Comment: I think so too. If you have subsequent questions, please ask a new question and include the relevant code and error message.

Answer (score 0):

Very subtle issue but your connection string line is the problem i.e.

```
string objConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Server"].ToString();
```

`ConnectionStrings['xxx']` returns an object and not the string itself, you want

```
string objConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Server"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: True, but that would reproduce another error as the one in the question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman think this does address the one in the question, unless I'm missing another error? I can only see one.

Comment: The `ToString` won't let the instantiation of the class fail. It still reproduces a string, although an invalid one. Later on, it will fail because of the invalid connection string, but that is long after the class is created.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes... this is true, and unlikely that `ToString` would throw unless the configuration didn't exist (which it appears to).

Comment: I think its because of the connection string on my web config. Because the same class works on my friend

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia well that was my initial thought but you seem to have the connections string, have you perhaps placed it in the wrong part of your web.config? A simple test would be to perform a `Console.WriteLine` in the constructor of `dbconn`. Regardless, in your current code you aren't pulling the string out correctly so please update with the code in my answer.

Comment: how should i put it? im sorry i'm so not familliar with this.

Answer (score -2):

Never ever manually create json. It is more time consuming and error prone than using a json serializer in whatever language you are working with.

What you are creating is invalid due to improper quotes!

Use `JSON.stringify()` on an object instead

```
data: JSON.stringify({'domain': username , 'accountpassword':  password }),
```

Comment: That is not the issue. You are solving another issue (and duplicating a deleted answer as you can see).

Comment: @PatrickHofman must have valid JSON to start with. Deleted answer still used invalid quotes. Perhaps there are other back end issues but at least having valid input to start with will help